# Interaction Failed discord.py Buttons

Tags: python

```
@client.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(
        "Support Tickets",
        components = [
            Button(label = "General", style=ButtonStyle.red)
        ]
    )

    interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("General"))
    await interaction.respond(content = "Creating The Ticket...")
```

I currently have this code. I am trying to make a button that has multiple uses, but for whatever reason I can only click this button once before it gives me a "This interaction failed" message. Is there anyway to fix this?

(I know that discord.py doesn't fully support this, but hopefully someone could assist me)

Where I got my information from the beginning from: https://pypi.org/project/discord-components/

Answer (score 1):

The `client.wait_for` will only wait for the first time that the event happens. If you want this button to be always pressable, then you could simply put it in a `while True:` loop to infinity repeat it, although it might make more sense to have your interaction handlers in a separate task so that there aren't multiple `wait_for`s, and is instead just one that handles all of the buttons sent, while the command just sends new ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Could you please assist/explain to me how I would use the while True: loop. 

Thanks!

Comment: You could just put the `wait_for` the interaction and the `interaction.respond` in the `while True` loop. Although like I mentioned, I think it would be better to create a separate task which loops this and you start once.

Comment: `  
interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("General"))
    while True:
      await interaction.respond(content = "Creating The Ticket...")` 
I'm still having quite a few issues understanding how to use the while True loop. Could you possibly provide an example and maybe what I'm doing wrong as that could help me a lot?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

make that:

```py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    current = 0
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(
        embed=bot.help_pages[current],
        components=[[Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="<<"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="<"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label=">"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label=">>")]])
    while True:
        previous_page = current
        moderatorI = await bot.wait_for("button_click") #this tests: "is button pressed"
        if moderatorI.component.label == '<<':  #and this: "witch is button is pressed"
            current = 0

        if moderatorI.component.label == '<':
            if current > 0:
                current -= 1

        if moderatorI.component.label == '>':
            if current < len(bot.help_pages) - 1:
                current += 1

        if moderatorI.component.label == '>>':
            current = len(bot.help_pages) - 1

        if current != previous_page:
            await msg.edit(embed=bot.help_pages[current])
            await moderatorI.respond(content=f"page: {current}")
```