# Can someone help me with my error when i press a button in discord.py

Tags: python, button, attributeerror

I'm trying to create an event that sends an embed with two buttons, one that handles a different command and the other to click when you don't need help, so that the mention and the embed are cleared.

This is the code I just got:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    s = client.get_command("yeet")
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        txt = discord.Embed(title="What's up? You need some help?",
                            color=discord.Colour.dark_gold())
        txt.add_field(name="Press the `Help` button if you want to see every command that i have",
                      value="Press the `Nvm` button if you didn't mean to mention me")
        g = await message.channel.send(
            embed=txt,
            components=[[Button(style=2, label="Help"), Button(style=3, label="Nvm")]]
        )
        try:
            hel = await client.wait_for("button_click", timeout=120)
            if hel.component.label == "Help":
                await client.process_commands(s)
            elif hel.component.label == "Nvm":
                await hel.respond(content="Oh okey no problem", ephemeral=False)
        except TimeoutError:
            time = discord.Embed(title="You're out of time try again", colour=discord.Colour.dark_magenta())
            await g.edit(embed=time)
```

The thing is i get this error if i press the "Help" button

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\PycharmProjects\Dipps\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Nutzer/PycharmProjects/Dipps/Main/Test Files/button commands.py", line 76, in on_message
    await client.process_commands(s)
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\PycharmProjects\Dipps\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 936, in process_commands
    if message.author.bot:
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: I think, you need to change `await client.process_commands(s)` to `client.process_commands(message)`, because in discord.py documentation we can find information about process_commands. And we need to use `await process_commands(message)`, Message class, not a Command class

Comment: Tryed it but then it just says "This interaction failed" under the message but no errors in the console

Comment: Maybe it can help to you
[Interaction Failed discord.py Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052625/interaction-failed-discord-py-buttons)