# Discord components (buttons), interaction don't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im here to ask for some help concerning my discord bot in python, so i imported the `discord_component` and started making a command with button, i managed to successfully add buttons to a embed message, but when i added the interactions i encountered some issues, even after adding them in multiple ways, i still had the "interaction error" when i clicked the buttons !

here is my code (the code is on repl.it and there is not errors in the console)

```py
@client.command()
async def bp_call(ctx,*args):
        
      message = "some description"
      ebd = discord.Embed(title="Support Call", description=message, color= discord.Colour.purple())
      
      msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=ebd,components=[
        [
          Button(style=5,label="Join",url="https://www.randomlink.com",custom_id="J"),
          Button(style=ButtonStyle.red,label="Leave",custom_id="L"),
          Button(style=ButtonStyle.green,label="Next Ping"),
          Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue,label="End Call",custom_id="EC"),
        ]
      ])
      
      itr = await client.wait_for("button_click")
      if itr.component.label == "Leave":
           await itr.respond(content="You left !")
```

Comment: Sending any errors can help us help you.

Comment: sadly there is no error in the console

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052625/interaction-failed-discord-py-buttons

Comment: thank you for giving me this link, but sadly the solution on  that thread didn't help much with my problem

Comment: Do you see the message (`You left !`) ?

Comment: no it doesn't show me the message, the only thing it shows me is "Interaction failed" under the message